# Showing a sequence is always bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ : if $n > m \ge N$ then $a_n < a_m + \epsilon$.

Prove that this sequence is always bounded above.

Comment: I'm not sure it's bounded above

Comment: Please do not deface your post by removing the text of your question. This makes the hard work of the answerers useless.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\epsilon =1$. There exists $N$ such that $a_n <a_m+1$ for $n >m \geq N$. Take $m=N$. We get $a_n <a_N+1$ for all $n >N$. Hence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above by $\max \{a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_N,a_n+1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis, using $\epsilon=1$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that
$$a_n < a_m + 1$$
for all $n,m$ with $n > m\ge N$.

In particular, using $m=N$, we get
$$a_n < a_N + 1$$
for all $n > N$.

Hence the subsequence
$$a_N,a_{N+1},a_{N+2},...$$
is bounded above by $a_N + 1$.

It follows that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded above by 
$$\max(u,a_N+1)$$
where $u\in\mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for the finite set $\{a_k\mid k < N\}$.